# Does gravity affect quantum fluctuations?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, gravity, event-horizon

Empty space is filled with quantum fluctuations. My question is, since space is affected by the amount of matter contained in it (based on General Relativity), does gravity affect quantum fluctuations? What happens to the quantum fluctuations near an event horizon? Also, do quantum fluctuations remain unchanged even as the space expands?

Comment: *"Empty space is filled with quantum fluctuations."* is a completely vacuous statement. What do you actually *mean* by that? What is your definition of "quantum fluctuation"? (If you look at other questions on this site, you will find that there is no universal definition all would agree upon)

Comment: Related: [Does time dilation destroy quantum superposition?](http://physicsworld.com/cws/article/news/2015/jun/19/does-time-dilation-destroy-quantum-superposition) (Physics world).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We don't know. Measuring effects of gravity at the microscopic scale is currently out of reach, since gravity is so weak compared to the strengths of all other interactions. This makes getting a clear signal so difficult.

We do not have anything near a testable theory of quantum gravity, so all answers must remain speculation. Some well-known physicists do in fact conjecture that gravity has an effect on quantum fluctuations (e.g. Penrose in *[The Emperor's New Mind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Emperor%27s_New_Mind)*).

Comment: Indeed, we don't know.  Further research on [Hawking radiation](http://www.technologyreview.com/view/420940/first-observation-of-hawking-radiation/) may eventually throw some light on the part of the question about event horizons.  However, if the OP specifically meant black hole event horizons, then that's still beyond detection, let alone measurement.